# Create list of only non-empty/non-null dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pydantic

I'm creating a model in Pydantic to get a JSON-like format from a dataframe.

What I have so far is this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List, Deque, Union
from collections.abc import Sequence

class startDate (BaseModel):
    year: int
    month: int
    day: int

class endDate (BaseModel):
    year: int
    month: int
    day: int

class origin(BaseModel):
    id: str

class destinations(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = None
        
class transfers_list(BaseModel):
    unloadingDuration: Optional[str] = None
    destination: Optional[destinations] = None

class frequency(BaseModel):
    id: str

class routeDetails (BaseModel):
    arrivalTime: str
    loadingStartTime: str
    loadingDuration: str
    releaseVehicleDuration: str
    vehicleType: str
    carrierId: str
    returnRoute: bool
    dock: Optional[str]
    origin: origin
    transfers: Optional[list[transfers_list]] = None
    frequency: frequency
    
class main (BaseModel):
    region: str
    startDate: startDate
    endDate: endDate
    recurrenceDays: list[int]
    routeDetails: routeDetails
    
class head (BaseModel):
    recurrenceSchedule: main
             
m = main(region='ABC',
         startDate={'year': 2023,
                    'month': 1,
                    'day': 1},
         endDate={'year': 2023,
                  'month': 1,
                  'day': 1},
         recurrenceDays=[5],
         routeDetails = {'arrivalTime':'09:00:00',
                         'loadingStartTime':'09:00:00',
                         'loadingDuration':'09:00:00',
                         'releaseVehicleDuration':'09:00:00',
                         'vehicleType':"truck",
                         'carrierId':"carrier_name",
                         'returnRoute':True,
                         'dock': None,
                         'origin': origin(id="NYC"),
                         'transfers': [transfers_list(unloadingDuration='10s', destination=destinations(id='id_destination')),transfers_list(unloadingDuration=None, destination=destinations(id=None))],
                         'frequency': frequency(id='247') 
                        }
        )


final = (head(recurrenceSchedule = m))
final = final.json(exclude_unset=True,exclude_defaults=True)
print(final)
```

And the Output is this:

```
{
   "recurrenceSchedule":{
      "region":"ABC",
      "startDate":{
         "year":2023,
         "month":1,
         "day":1
      },
      "endDate":{
         "year":2023,
         "month":1,
         "day":1
      },
      "recurrenceDays":[
         5
      ],
      "routeDetails":{
         "arrivalTime":"09:00:00",
         "loadingStartTime":"09:00:00",
         "loadingDuration":"09:00:00",
         "releaseVehicleDuration":"09:00:00",
         "vehicleType":"truck",
         "carrierId":"carrier_name",
         "returnRoute":true,
         "origin":{
            "id":"NYC"
         },
         "transfers":[
            {
               "unloadingDuration":"10s",
               "destination":{
                  "id":"id_destination"
               }
            },
            {
               "destination":{
                  
               }
            }
         ],
         "frequency":{
            "id":"247"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is almost exactly what I need, but in my Dataframe I have other columns for unloadingDuration and Destination that are inside "Transfers". However, when the value in the DF is empty/null/None, I don't want another dictionary inside the list. My desired output is:

```
"transfers":[
            {
               "unloadingDuration":"10s",
               "destination":{
                  "id":"id_destination"
               }
            }
         ]
```

Instead of this:

```
"transfers":[
            {
               "unloadingDuration":"10s",
               "destination":{
                  "id":"id_destination"
               }
            },
            {
               "destination":{
                  
               }
            }
         ]
```

I have tried changing my NaN fields (unloadingDuration and destination) in the dataframe to None, but this doesn't work.

I tried changing some classes to Optional back and forth and this didn't seem to work either.

I also used **exclude_unset=True** and **exclude_defaults=True** that do work in some cases (dock is Optional, and when I set it to null it simply doesn't show up).

Comment: The _M_ in [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is actually important. Your post shows that you did not even try to reduce the problem to the essentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try [excluding none](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson) values:

```
final = final.json(exclude_unset=True, exclude_none=True)
```